# Viewing Google Earth in offline mode

Tags: google-earth

I have a tablet (Android 4.1) which does not have 3G internet. I have installed Google Earth and I heard that there is a solution for viewing maps offline.

How do I do that?

Comment: http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-download-offline-maps-in-google-maps/

Comment: @Davidenko: Google Maps <> Google Earth

Comment: Related discussion on [Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/earth/UEwApJ-OfUc)

Answer (score 1):

As of current writing, Google Earth doesn't support full offline mode, in which you can specify to download certain location's satellite imagery in detail. However, just like Google Maps, you can cache a small portion of it for offline viewing.

Quoting [Google Earth product support](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/21423),

> Google Earth works best with a live internet connection. You can, however, cache (save) small amounts of data that you can access when you're offline.
>
> To do so, log on to the internet and visit the imagery you'd like to view while you're offline. Please pay attention to the Streaming indicator, which appears just below and a little to the right of your images. When this indicator has reached 100% for the imagery you're viewing, Google Earth has gathered all available data for that specific altitude and settings, so you can disconnect from the internet.
>
> Please remember that once you're disconnected, you'll be able to view cached areas only.

Note: there's no streaming indicator in Google Earth app. Instead, you can wait until the images are fully loaded.

Comment: Note that downloading Google Earth's data probably won't be feasible due to [its size](https://www.quora.com/If-I-were-to-download-Google-Maps-all-of-it-for-offline-use-how-much-data-would-be-consumed). Compared to Maps, which its data can be compressed significantly (using vector instead of real image), Earth comprises of fully image.

Answer (score 0):

If its not too much data you are looking for, you can try to clear the cache before you want to save something for offline use. But the cache size is not too big, so don't expect too much.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know of, there is a "make available offline" option which allows one to select and download the most recent version of a portion of the map. Of course, you'll need an Internet connection to download it first. How to:
  Menu>Make Available Offline; 
  From there you should be able to select a region to download.

Comment: Google Earth doesn't have such a menu item. Could you be thinking of Google Maps?

Comment: But of course, silly me.